# Centos7 systemctl start unit not found

Tags: centos7, systemctl, google-cloud-sql

I look everywhere and just for the life of me figure out why systemctl would not start my unit.

I am trying to start GCP's cloud-sql-proxy as a systemd service. This is what my `cloud-sql-proxy.service` looks like.

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Unit]
Description=Cloud SQL Proxy
Requires=networking.service
After=networking.service

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/opt
ExecStart=/opt/cloud_sql_proxy -instances=pupa=tcp:5432 -credential_file=/etc/pupa-240309-5336639b0c06.json
Restart=always
StandardOutput=journal
User=root
```

I ran `sudo systemctl enable cloud-sql-proxy` successfully. Then when I execute `sudo systemctl start cloud-sql-proxy.service` it failed with this message:

```
Failed to start cloud-sql-proxy.service: Unit not found.
```

Here are more information:

```
$ ll -al /etc/systemd/system/cloud-sql-proxy.service
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 327 May 22 10:56 /etc/systemd/system/cloud-sql-proxy.service

$ sudo systemctl list-unit-files
...
cloud-sql-proxy.service                       enabled
...

$ systemctl status cloud-sql-proxy
● cloud-sql-proxy.service - Cloud SQL Proxy
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/cloud-sql-proxy.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since Sun 2019-05-19 15:49:48 UTC; 3 days ago
 Main PID: 1414 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 19 15:49:48 instance-1 systemd[1]: cloud-sql-proxy.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 19 15:49:48 instance-1 systemd[1]: Unit cloud-sql-proxy.service entered failed state.
May 19 15:49:48 instance-1 systemd[1]: cloud-sql-proxy.service failed.
May 19 15:49:48 instance-1 systemd[1]: cloud-sql-proxy.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
May 19 15:49:48 instance-1 systemd[1]: cloud-sql-proxy.service failed to schedule restart job: Unit not found.
May 19 15:49:48 instance-1 systemd[1]: Unit cloud-sql-proxy.service entered failed state.
May 19 15:49:48 instance-1 systemd[1]: cloud-sql-proxy.service failed.
```

Any suggestion on where I missed?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try something like this in /usr/lib/systemd/system/cloud_sql_proxy.service

```
[Unit]
Description=GCP CloudSQL Proxy
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/usr/bin
Type=forking
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/nohup /usr/local/cloud_sql_proxy -instances=${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME} -credential_file=${CREDENTIAL_FILE} &'
StandardOutput=journal
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Your config file will be /usr/lib/systemd/system/cloud_sql_proxy.service.d/settings.conf

```
[Service]
Environment=INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=[YOUR CONNECTION NAME]
Environment=CREDENTIAL_FILE=[PATH TO YOUR CREDENTIAL FILE]
```

Comment: Removing `Requires=networking.service` did the trick!
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

In my experience, this has been due to one of the services in `Requires` not being found.  If you're able to enable your service but starting your service returns `Unit not found` then examine the services under `Requires`.  In my case, I had a `Requires: rpcbind.service` but that service was not installed on my system.

Comment: wow not a fun error message.  In my case the required unit existed but was system level.  The unit I was trying to start was user level.  Per another SO answer "User units can not reference or depend on system units." https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278572/24314

Answer (score 1):

I think you're following this [[1]](https://gist.github.com/goodwill/a981c2912ae6a83761a624f657f34d9f) link, but if you look at the bottom, they specify that you need to use a different file if you want to do the same on Centos 7. Maybe that is why it is failing.

For Centos 7, use the following:

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Unit]
Description=Google Cloud Compute Engine SQL Proxy
Requires=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/usr/local/bin
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/var/run/cloud-sql-proxy -instances=<instance_connection_name>=tcp:3306 -credential_file=/var/local/cloud-sql-proxy/<credential_json>.json
Restart=always
StandardOutput=journal
```

[1] https://gist.github.com/goodwill/a981c2912ae6a83761a624f657f34d9f

Comment: Could you please provide directly in your answer the settings which should, as you think, help